# The logic behind `reorder()` in `R`?

Tags: r

I have difficulties understanding the logic behind `reorder()`.

Suppose `Var` is defined as below:

```
Var <- factor(c(0.2, 0.1, -0.1))
order(Var)
```

Now if I want to reorder it to c(1, 2, 3) I would run the following code, which works perfectly fine.

```
Needed_Order <- c(1, 2, 3)
Var <- reorder(Var, Needed_Order)
order(Var)
```

But it does not work if I want to reorder `Var` to c(3, 1, 2)

```
Needed_Order <- c(3,1,2)
Var <- reorder(Var, Needed_Order)
order(Var)
```

I expect to get `3 1 2` as the output of `order(var)` but it returns `2 3 1`.

Comment: Why do you expect to get that?  If you want to reorder the levels, you should supply the actual levels.  If you read the help file for reorder (?reorder)  you will see `bymedian <- with(InsectSprays, reorder(spray, count, median))`  which shows you that you don't supply an array of nubers, you have to supply a function that will be used for the ordering.

Comment: @Elin so what function should I use if I want a particular order, which cannot be defined by a function? Note that I do not want to supply the actual levels, as there are so many of them and I need to repeat this process many times

Comment: Well what is the order you want? If it's not the levels themselves then you will need to provide some other values that are ***actually found in the data ***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think @prosoitos already has a great answer.  I just wanted to illustrate why the `reorder` function exists and how it's useful.

## Ordering Groups in a Plot

Let's consider the classic `iris` dataset

```
> data(iris)
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

and suppose we want to plot the `Sepal.Width` values, comparing by `Species`

```
boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ Species, iris)
```

[image]

but the order here is by species name, whereas we think the plot would look nicer if we ordered by the mean sepal width of each species.  And that's where `reorder` is a quick, powerful solution for this:

```
iris$Species <- reorder(iris$Species, iris$Sepal.Width, FUN=mean)
boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ Species, iris)
```

[image]

What happened here is that the `iris$Sepal.Width` values corresponding to each level in `iris$Species` had the function `mean` applied to them and the result was attached to the factor as the `scores` attribute:

```
> attr(iris$Species, 'scores')
    setosa versicolor  virginica
     3.428      2.770      2.974
```

These scores were then used to rank (in ascending order) the levels in the factor, and assign them that order:

```
> levels(iris$Species)
[1] "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"
```

Note that this doesn't change the order of any of the *data* in the data frame, but only the order of the codes used in the factor.  The `FUN` argument makes the `reorder` function quite general, so that one could order by min or max or whatever function you'd like to compute on the grouped data.

Overall, I think the key thing is that the second argument in the `reorder` function, which was thought to be a desired order, is instead for inputting the weights or values associated to each entry in the factor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is in fact what I was looking for :)

Comment: And the forcats function which does that is `fct_reorder()`

Answer (score 2):

The function `lvls_reorder()` from the tidyverse package forcats does what you want:

```
Var <- factor(c(0.2, 0.1, -0.1))
Needed_Order <- c(3, 1, 2)
Var <- forcats::lvls_reorder(Var, Needed_Order)
order(Var)
```

**Result**

```
[1] 3 1 2
```

---

**Explanations**

Let's use an example with distinct elements for the values, the levels and the order positions of the levels to make it easier to visualize what is going on:

```
f <- factor(c(a = "A", b = "B", c = "C"))
f
# a b c 
# A B C 
# Levels: A B C

order(f)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Now, let's use `stats::reorder()`:

```
reorder(f, c(3, 1, 2))
# a b c 
# A B C 
# attr(,"scores")
# A B C 
# 3 1 2 
# Levels: B C A
```

`reorder()` assigns the values `3 1 2` as `"scores" attributes` for the levels `A B C` and reorders those levels according to these scores: reordering the scores to `1 2 3` reorders the levels to `B C A`.

Since `order()` returns a permutation which rearranges the factor into (by default) an ascending order, we get:

```
order(reorder(f, c(3, 1, 2)))
# [1] 2 3 1
```

In comparison, `forcats::lvls_reorder()` simply reorders the levels by indexing them with the values `3 1 2` (what you were trying to do):

```
lvls_reorder(f, c(3, 1, 2))
# a b c
# A B C
# Levels: C A B
```

Which gives the order:

```
order(lvls_reorder(f, c(3, 1, 2)))
# [1] 3 1 2
```

Comment: One thing I'd suggest adding to this is how `reorder` actually computes the `scores` attribute, because that is then what is used to determine the new order for the `levels` attribute. It is sort of obscured in both OP and here because you both used vectors where the number of levels equals the number of entries, so you never see what the `FUN=mean` argument is doing.

Comment: Right. I've been editing my answer a million times already and I still have a very obscure explanation. I am still working on it :P Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Note: feel free to post a new answer with a great explanation if you want. I am still battling it and I am sure that you would do this much better (I never use factors and while I know what works, it isn't yet very clear to me why things work the way they do. Which is why it is taking me so much time to explain it...)

Comment: Oh, it's definitely already a good, insightful answer (+1)! That `reorder` function is just weird though. Definitely an artifact of statisticians designing the base language.

Comment: The forcats version sure is more intuitive :P

Comment: @merv: I am finally done battling with my explanation. If it is erroneous or incomplete, please feel free to criticize it. I would certainly appreciate the feed-back. Thank you!

Comment: @prosoitos: Thanks for your insightful answer. This was helpful for me